# Is there a way to select data from one column in SQL table to get table with multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two SQL tables: one with id and in the other is meta value and meta_key. I joined them so it looks something like this:

```
+------+------------+----------+
|  id  | meta_value | meta_key |
+------+------------+----------+
| 1544 | product1   |        1 |
| 1544 | 2          |        2 |
| 1545 | product2   |        1 |
| 1545 | 5          |        2 |
| 1546 | product3   |        1 |
| 1546 | 10         |        2 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

And I want to get a query that would show me a table like this:

```
+------+------------+------------+
|  id  | meta_value | meta_value |
+------+------------+------------+
| 1544 | product1   |          2 |
| 1545 | product2   |          5 |
| 1546 | product3   |         10 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

The SQL query for first table looks like this:

```
SELECT
    wprq_gf_entry.id,
    wprq_gf_entry_meta.meta_value,
    wprq_gf_entry_meta.meta_key 
FROM
    wprq_gf_entry 
    INNER JOIN wprq_gf_entry_meta ON wprq_gf_entry.id = wprq_gf_entry_meta.entry_id 
WHERE
    wprq_gf_entry_meta.form_id = 6
```

Is there a way to do this? ... Thank you!

Comment: Why `wprq_gf_entry_meta.form_id = 6` twice?

Comment: @jarlh . . . Why once?  It seems to have nothing to do with the sample data.

Comment: @jarlh sorry it was a mistake. Once is enough.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It actually has nothing to do with sample data, but it has with my code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`, but you need two of them:

```
SELECT e.*, m1.meta_value, m2.meta_value
FROM wprq_gf_entry e JOIN
     wprq_gf_entry_meta m1
     ON e.id = m1.entry_id AND m1.meta_key = 1 JOIN
     wprq_gf_entry_meta m2
     ON e.id = m2.entry_id AND m2.meta_key = 2;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code does not work for me... I am also a beginner in sql so if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table you created, let's call it joined_table.

```
With joined_table as(
    SELECT
        wprq_gf_entry.id,
        wprq_gf_entry_meta.meta_value,
        wprq_gf_entry_meta.meta_key 
    FROM wprq_gf_entry 
         INNER JOIN wprq_gf_entry_meta ON wprq_gf_entry.id 
         = wprq_gf_entry_meta.entry_id 
    WHERE wprq_gf_entry_meta.form_id = 6
    
)
```

Were dividing it into two tables - one with meta-key = 1 and the other with meta-key = 2.
Then, we are joining them

```
Select jt.id, jt.meta_value as meta_value_1, 
            jt2.meta_value as meta_value_2
From joined_table jt
         Join joined_table jt2 
         On jt.id = jt2.id
         And jt2.meta_key = 2
Where jt.meta_key = 1
```